# Need to filter only some of the cells in Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

i am populating some data to rad grid and i need to filter some data if user needs. so i checked the filtering option. but now filtering condition is applied to all the cells.So i need it to be on 2 cells and how can it be possible.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellSpacing="0" DataSourceID="Patdetails" GridLines="None" 
                onneeddatasource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" ForeColor="#7090A1" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
                >
```

```
 <Columns>
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn column" 
        HeaderText="Select" UniqueName="TemplateColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_slct_pat" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name"  AllowFiltering="true"
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" HeaderText="Name"
        UniqueName="column">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Sex" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" HeaderText="Gender" 
        UniqueName="column1">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="age" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" HeaderText="Age" 
        UniqueName="column2">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dob" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column3 column" HeaderText="DOB" 
        UniqueName="column3">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="hspt" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column4 column" HeaderText="Visit ID" 
        UniqueName="column4">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="physician" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column5 column" HeaderText="Physician" 
        UniqueName="column5">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PCU" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column6 column" HeaderText="PCU" 
        UniqueName="column6">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

```
<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Patdetails" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testdb_string %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT  TOP (50) Name,CASE WHEN Sex = 'F' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Male' END AS Sex, Age,('*'+RTRIM(pv.hs])+('*')) AS hspt, PCU, [Discharge Date],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert(date,[Date of Birth]), 101) as dob,pv.Physician,pv.[Admit Date]  FROM Patient_view AS pv WHERE ([Discharge Date] IS NULL) ORDER BY PCU">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the filtering property to the column where you do not won't to have the filter and set it:

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" Header.........
```

[image: Saple]

Comment: ya I got . What the issue is when i set this property initially it won't work. and later, when i set 'AllowFiltering="false" ShowFilterIcon="false" ', it works perfect for me. thanks for your answer.

Comment: some times its hard to set simple things... now also i am behind some thing like this